# Insert string at andom index is not working swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, numbers, generator

I am working on a random password generator and I want to have a base string that a user can input, and have random characters generated inside or around the base string. My problem is that whenever it generates random characters with the base string, they get inserted in the front (0th index). Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var baseStringTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lowerCaseSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var upperCaseSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfCharactersSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfCharsLabel: UILabel!

    let lower = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t","u","v","w", "x", "y", "z"]
    let upper = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

    let lowerUpper = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
        "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
        "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",]

    let lowerNumber = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
        "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
        "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

    let upperNumber = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

    let all = ["a", "A" ,"b", "B", "c", "C", "d", "D", "e", "E" , "f", "F", "g", "G",  "h", "H", "i", "I",  "j", "J" ,"k", "K", "l", "L" ,"m", "M" , "n", "N" ,"o", "O", "p", "P",  "q", "Q", "r", "R", "s", "S", "t", "T", "u", "U", "v", "V", "w", "W", "x","X", "y", "Y" , "z", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

    var generatedString = [""]


    func generateLower(){
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var char = lower[Int(arc4random_uniform(26))]
            var count_ = baseString.count
            var baseStringText = baseStringTextField.text
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + count(baseStringText.utf16))))
            baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    func generateUpper(){
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var char = upper[Int(arc4random_uniform(26))]
            var count_ = baseString.count
            var baseStringText = baseStringTextField.text
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + count(baseStringText.utf16))))
            baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    func generateNumber(){
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var char = numbers[Int(arc4random_uniform(10))]
            var count_ = baseString.count
            var baseStringText = baseStringTextField.text
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + count(baseStringText.utf16))))
            baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    func generateLowerAndUpper(){
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var count_ = baseString.count
            var baseStringText = baseStringTextField.text
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + count(baseStringText.utf16))))
                var char = lowerUpper[Int(arc4random_uniform(52))]
                baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    func generateLowerAndNumber(){
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var count_ = baseString.count
            var baseStringText = baseStringTextField.text
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + count(baseStringText.utf16))))
                var char = lowerNumber[Int(arc4random_uniform(36))]
                baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    func generateUpperAndNumber(){
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var count_ = baseString.count
            var baseStringText = baseStringTextField.text
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + count(baseStringText.utf16))))
                var char = upperNumber[Int(arc4random_uniform(36))]
                baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    func generateAll(){
        srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
        var baseString:[String] = Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(roundf(numberOfCharactersSlider.value)) ; ++i{
            var count_ = baseString.count
            println(count_)
            var randIndex:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_)))
            var char = all[Int(arc4random_uniform(62))]
            baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
        }
        generatedString = baseString
        generatedStringLabel.text = "".join(generatedString)
    }

    @IBAction func generateString(sender: UIButton) {
        if(lowerCaseSwitch.on && upperCaseSwitch.on && numberSwitch.on){
            generateAll()
        }else if(lowerCaseSwitch.on && upperCaseSwitch.on == false && numberSwitch.on == false){
            generateLower()
        }else if(upperCaseSwitch.on && lowerCaseSwitch.on == false && numberSwitch.on == false){
            generateUpper()
        }else if(numberSwitch.on && lowerCaseSwitch.on == false  && upperCaseSwitch.on == false){
            generateNumber()
        }else if(lowerCaseSwitch.on && upperCaseSwitch.on && numberSwitch.on == false){
            generateLowerAndUpper()
        }else if(lowerCaseSwitch.on && numberSwitch.on && upperCaseSwitch.on == false){
            generateLowerAndNumber()
        }else if(upperCaseSwitch.on && numberSwitch.on && lowerCaseSwitch.on == false){
            generateUpperAndNumber()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func copyButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "".join(generatedString)
}
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you condense your question into a minimum working example? We don't know which method is wrong or what the incorrect result looks like.

Comment: It’s not just that you’ll get a better answer from a more minimal working example – it’s absolutely critical for your future sanity that you factor the business logic of generating the password _out_ from the logic of your view controller. It will be so much easier for you in the long run if you do this.

Comment: For starters, this looks suspect... count(baseStringText.utf16) try instead (baseStringText.utf16).count

Comment: `srandom()` is unnecessary, `arc4random()` does not need seeding explicit seeding. There is no need to use urf16, in Swift 1.2 and up String length is properly supported: count( "i⃝") is 3.

Comment: @IanClay Actually `count(baseStringText.utf16)` is correct albeit why `utf16` is a mystery.

Comment: @zaph The `utf16` view of `String` is the only one that is random access (because that’s how Swift strings are held internally).  So if you know your string only contains simple characters it is much more efficient.  Course, if it doesn’t contain simple characters, the answer will be wrong!

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity the `.utf16` is not being used as an index, it is being used as a length.

Comment: @zaph yes, but that length can be computed in constant time with a random-access index, but only in linear time on the characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is going to be extremely hard to debug, because it mixes together lots of different things – fetching random elements from arrays, building strings from random elements, updating UIs, getting settings from UIs to control code.

You will find it much much easier to write correct code on the first try, and get yourself out of debugging hell, if you get into the habit of decomposing what you need to do into multiple building blocks.

Which building blocks to build is something that only comes with practice, but a good sign that you have a problem is if you find yourself repeating the same identical code with minor variations over and over again, as you do in your various `generateXXX` functions – these are examples of breaking up your code in a way that *isn’t* useful.

For example, you need a function that generates passwords of a given length, optionally including various kinds of character.  For that, you need a function that fetches a random character from an array (or any collection).  For that, you need a function that converts a system-generated random number into an index into the collection.  Those would probably make good building blocks.

So, a function that converts `arc4random_uniform` (btw there’s no need to call `srand`, `arc4random` seeds itself):

(all the below is Swift 2.0 code, but unless you’re planning to ship something to production in less than 3 months, and especially if you’re learning Swift, I’d strongly suggest upgrading since it is *much* easier to use than 1.2, and you’ll have to upgrade eventually which can be painful the longer you leave it)

```
/// Version of arc4random that works for any integer type. Kinda ugly unfortunately.
func arc4random_uniform<In: _SignedIntegerType, Out: _SignedIntegerType>(upto: In) -> Out 
{
    precondition(upto < numericCast(UInt32.max),"Range too big for arc4random")
    return numericCast(Darwin.arc4random_uniform(numericCast(upto.toIntMax())))
}
```

Then a function that fetches a random element from a collection. This works on any collection type generically, but you could just write it for arrays since if that’s all you need, which would be easier to do:

```
/// Fetch a random element from any collection that supports random access
extension CollectionType where Index: RandomAccessIndexType {
    var randomElement: Generator.Element {
        guard !isEmpty else { fatalError("Collection cannot be empty") }
        return self[startIndex.advancedBy(arc4random_uniform(count))]
    }
}
```

Then, a option set for the different kinds of characters you might want to include:

```
/// A set of options for controlling which characters to include in a password
struct CharacterOptions: OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let LowerCase = CharacterOptions(rawValue: 1)
    static let UpperCase = CharacterOptions(rawValue: 2)
    static let Numbers = CharacterOptions(rawValue: 4)

    /// An array of the full set of characters based on the options set
    var characters: [Character] {
        let lower = Array("abcdefghijklmnop".characters)
        let upper = Array("ABCDEFGHIKKLMNOP".characters)
        let numbers = Array("1234567890".characters)

        // this could be done so much more efficiently if only
        // LazyRandomAccessCollection supported flatMap
        return (self.contains(.LowerCase) ? lower   : [])
             + (self.contains(.UpperCase) ? upper   : [])
             + (self.contains(.Numbers)   ? numbers : [])
    }
}
```

Finally, put them together into a function that generates passwords:

```
func generatePassword(length: Int, options: CharacterOptions) -> String {
    let sources: [Character] = options.characters

    let characters = (0..<length).map { _ in
        sources.randomElement
    }

    return String(characters)
}

generatePassword(10, options: [.LowerCase, .UpperCase])
```

Then, when you’ve built this random-password-generating function, you should call it from your view controller.  But you don’t have to - you can just call it stand-alone, and that makes it far easier to test and check it’s working, and to debug. The stand-alone functions can also be tested independently.

Comment: How would a lazy flatMap() be useful?

Comment: @oisdk Because what I need is a “virtual” array that consists of an arbitrary number of subarrays, presented as a single contiguous array. It’d be much nicer to present this lazily, rather than having to rebuild a whole new array every time.

Comment: How about [this](https://gist.github.com/oisdk/60f1373019b91673ac54)? It's only one-directional, so it might not be applicable, but it works the same as `LazySequence<FilterSequenceView<`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @oisdk nice! here’s something you could also use to do it as a collection (very inefficient, but could be made efficient with more code): https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/08b0122228e614bf4cce

Comment: IMO: Shades of the worst of C++. Using neat language features that make the code hard to comprehend. One (me) has to read fairly deeply to understand the code and that makes maintenance difficult. Extending `CollectionType` is neat but also untested on other collections, collections that are not needed. Designing for a future that will most likely never happen. As Kent Beck said: "Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work" and I concur.

Comment: @zaph - you could instead write these as extensions to array and they would be much simpler. For this answer, I probably should have. However, that Beck quote is kind of like astrology predictions – it fits whatever argument you want to make. Is it “simpler” to write a massive long function instead of decomposing it into sub problems? Is it simpler to write a function that takes an array instead of extending collection type, only to find that later you want to use the same thing on a different collection type? Would `map` be better as an array method instead of an extension to CollectionType?

Comment: The implementation does not answer the question, rather it just generates a random string. The question is generating characters that are interspersed into a base string.

Comment: @zaph I also voted to close the question, because it is a classic “why isn’t this code working?” My code isn’t intended to answer the question directly, but rather some advice on how to write code differently – because I do truly believe that the reason the code doesn’t work is because it is without structure and _not_ because of one particular bug, and learning about building that structure is far more important than fixing this particular bug. You might disagree with the nature of the decomposition or that the generics are excessive, but there’s no denying that need for refactoring.

Comment: I certainly agree to OP's code it is without structure, contains code duplication and archaic code and in serious need of refactoring. Unfortunately the answer by @luk2302 conflated the UI (`UITextField` and `UISLider`) with the logic and also misses the letter/number options. Were he to refactor the UI out I would prefer that answer as being straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code (as the comments already told you). I got a version of of your functions working, namely the `generateUpperAndNumber`. The beginning of the following code is just for the function to be able to operate on valid data - what is of concern to you is the new implementation of `generateUpperAndNumber`:

```
var baseStringTextField = UITextField()
baseStringTextField.text = "myText"

var numberOfCharactersSlider = UISlider()
numberOfCharactersSlider.minimumValue = 1
numberOfCharactersSlider.maximumValue = 20
numberOfCharactersSlider.value = 13

let upperNumber:[Character] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

var generatedString:[Character] = []
var generatedStringLabel = UILabel()

func generateUpperAndNumber() {
    var baseString = Array(baseStringTextField.text!.characters)
    for var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfCharactersSlider.value) ; ++i {
        let count_ = baseString.count

        let randIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + 1)))
        let char = upperNumber[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperNumber.count)))]

        baseString.insert(char, atIndex: randIndex)
    }

    generatedString = baseString
    var genString = ""
    for c in baseString {
        genString += String(c)
    }
    generatedStringLabel.text = genString
}

generateUpperAndNumber()
```

One example output of this is *B***my***D***T***0Q***ext***X*

Let me explain a few points where you code did not work as intended:

- `Array(arrayLiteral: baseStringTextField.text)` returns an array with only the text as a single element in it. You wanted a array of all the character -> `Array(baseStringTextField.text!.characters)`
- Your randIndex did not make any sense at all. It should just pick an index between 0 and the size of the current array
- You have massive code duplication - only the characters that you insert differ -> pass the characters you want to choose from as a parameter of `generateX()`
- Instead of having a method that magically gets its relevant input from *somewhere* you should pass in the string of the textField as a parameter.

Comment: With the exception of not supporting the different letter & number combinations this works including with emoji. The only unfortunate thing about it is that it has the concept of textField embedded in place of a method that take arguments and return a result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take based on previous answers by luk2302 and Airspeed Velocity (Swift 2.0)

```
func insertionCharacters(lowerCase lowerCase: Bool, upperCase: Bool, numbers: Bool) -> String {
    var characters :String = ""
    if lowerCase {
        characters += "abcdefghijklmnop"
    }
    if upperCase {
        characters += "ABCDEFGHIKKLMNOP"
    }
    if numbers {
        characters += "1234567890"
    }
    return characters
}

func generatePasscode(length: Int, baseString: String, insertCharacters: String) -> String {
    let insertCharacterList = Array(insertCharacters.characters)
    let insertCharacterCount :UInt32 = UInt32(insertCharacterList.count)
    guard insertCharacterCount>0 else { return baseString}

    var baseArray = Array(baseString.characters)
    for _ in 0..<length {
        let count_ = baseArray.count

        let randIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count_ + 1)))
        let insertCharacterIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(insertCharacterCount))
        let insertCharacter = insertCharacterList[insertCharacterIndex]

        baseArray.insert(insertCharacter, atIndex: randIndex)
    }

    var genString = ""
    for c in baseArray {
        genString += String(c)
    }

    return genString
}
```

Usage Example:

```
func generate() {
    let baseString = baseStringTextField.text
    let insertCount = numberOfCharactersSlider.value

    let characters = insertionCharacters(lowercase:lowerCaseSwitch.on, upperCase:upperCaseSwitch.on, numbers:numberSwitch.on)
    let passcode = generatePasscode(insertCount, baseString:baseString, insertCharacters: characters)

    let baseStringTextField.text = passcode
}
generate()
```

Test:

```
func test() {
    let insertCount = 8
    let baseString = "unii⃝code"

    print("baseString: \(baseString)")
    let characters = insertionCharacters(lowerCase:false, upperCase:true, numbers:true)
    let passcode = generatePasscode(insertCount, baseString:baseString, insertCharacters: characters)
    print("passcode: \(passcode)")
}
test()
```

Test output:

> baseString: unii⃝code
>   passcode: 0uniG39i⃝3cHNod4e